# STRING Date to DATETIME - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and currently doing a practice. I have this table:

```
  CREATE TABLE runner_orders (
  "order_id" INTEGER,
  "runner_id" INTEGER,
  "pickup_time" VARCHAR(19),
  "distance" VARCHAR(7),
  "duration" VARCHAR(10),
  "cancellation" VARCHAR(23)
);

INSERT INTO runner_orders
  ("order_id", "runner_id", "pickup_time", "distance", "duration", "cancellation")
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2020-01-01 18:15:34', '20km', '32 minutes', ''),
  ('2', '1', '2020-01-01 19:10:54', '20km', '27 minutes', ''),
  ('3', '1', '2020-01-03 00:12:37', '13.4km', '20 mins', NULL),
  ('4', '2', '2020-01-04 13:53:03', '23.4', '40', NULL),
  ('5', '3', '2020-01-08 21:10:57', '10', '15', NULL),
  ('6', '3', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'Restaurant Cancellation'),
  ('7', '2', '2020-01-08 21:30:45', '25km', '25mins', 'null'),
  ('8', '2', '2020-01-10 00:15:02', '23.4 km', '15 minute', 'null'),
  ('9', '2', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'Customer Cancellation'),
  ('10', '1', '2020-01-11 18:50:20', '10km', '10minutes', 'null');
```

As you can see I need to change pickup_time to DATETIME, but when I do:

```
 ALTER TABLE runner_orders
ALTER COLUMN pickup_time DATETIME
```

I get 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

I Read other posts here and already tried:

- Removing the '-' to only have '20200101 18:15:34'
- Setting NULL = 0
- Adding a T in between Date and Time '2020-01-10T00:15:02'
- Manually changing the datatype with the Designer option

But nothing is working so far.

Comment: Maybe instead of `null`, set a default datetime, like `2001-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: try also convert the string value as follows: `convert(varchar, '2020-01-01 18:15:34', 20)` or similar

Comment: If NULL is in quotes that usually means it is TEXT string of null not the NULL value (or absence of value)

Comment: You can do an update and set date col where 'null' set to NULL.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd` is an ambiguous format for `datetime`. Use `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`. Or use a `datetime2(0)`, considering you have no milliseconds, then the error won't occur (provided you have valid dates, which `'null'` is not).

Comment: run: update t set pickup_time = null from runner_orders where pickup_time = 'null';  ALTER TABLE runner_orders
ALTER COLUMN pickup_time DATETIME

Comment: Ok I'll try all of these solutions as soon as I get home in 2 hours! Thank u and I'll keep y'all updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help

You have the String value 'null' in the pickup_time column which is throwing that error. Remove that column value 'null' by updating it as NULL. After that, you can able to alter

```
UPDATE runner_orders SET pickup_time = NULL WHERE pickup_time = 'null'

ALTER TABLE runner_orders ALTER COLUMN pickup_time DATETIME
```

Comment: `UPDATE runner_orders SET pickup_time = NULL` how does this "help" here by removing all the data values?  Please update with some details so the "new to sql" OP poster is best assisted here

Comment: The first part of this answer is correct - in the INSERT statement change 'null' to NULL (no quotes).  That will insert a NULL into the table for those columns instead of attempting to insert the string 'null'.  Since you have already modified the column to a DATETIME there isn't anything else needed.

Comment: in otherwords, the OP should be advised also to review how they insert data. Instead of
`('9', '2', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'Customer Cancellation'),` 
they likely want
`('9', '2', null, null, null, 'Customer Cancellation'),`

Comment: @gskarthikkn so I just tried this and it worked! thank u!

Comment: @Sean yeah that would be nice but this is just a small case study to practice and learn SQL, and changing it while I'm inserting the data is kinda cheating I think? Since the point is to change the data you are given